# C++, char*, segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I want to assign string from command line. But I got segmentation fault. why? here is the code:

```
char* ans;  
cout << "enter string: ";  
cin >> *ans;
```

update:
how to allocate memory in advance if I don't know the size of input string,
how it works in String Class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a pointer, but that pointer doesn't point to anywhere where there's space allocated for data to be stored.  Use `std::string` instead:

```
std::string ans;
cout << "enter string: ";  
cin >> ans;

// ...

ans.c_str(); // returns const char *
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you did not allocate any memory to `ans`.
This leads to **undefined behavior**, where the string that user inputs is written to some memory which does not belong to your variable `ans` and this causes the crash.
A better approach is to use `std::string` instead of `char *`.

```
std::string ans;
cout << "enter string: ";  
cin >> ans;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory to read your string into - in your code `ans` is uninitialized, and so could be pointing to any random memory location.  That's likely to cause a crash.  Is there a reason you don't want to use `string`?

Comment: I just play. decided to do it with char*. How will I allocate memory if I don't know size of the input text.

Comment: @michael - you can't know then.  Just take a best guess at allocating "enough" space or figure out the size of the input somehow.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *ans;
```

Defines a pointer, without initializing it. A pointer only points to some storage area, it doesn't hold it. And without initializing it, there's nowhere you could dereference it.

You need to do two things:

- Allocate some storage. Either define a static variable for this, or use dynamic storage using the `new` keyword.
- Initialize the pointer with the address of this storage.

Or do the better thing, don't operate with a naked pointer at all and use a `std::string` which will take care of all the details of memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

By using a `char*` you are attempting to write to memory you do not own, and the OS is halting your application before it can do any damage.

Instead, try something like:

```
#include <string>

std::string ans;
cout << "enter string: ";
cin >> ans;

const char* ans_str = ans.c_str();
```